# Swift: NSMutableAttributedString foregroundColor not setting properly

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I need the first character of my UILabel to be a different color than the rest of the label. I'm using the following code:

```
        let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cell.label.text!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1))
        cell.label.attributedText = attributedString
```

This is just causing the first character to vanish. A print statement for attributedString looks like this (apparently correct):

```
■{NSForegroundColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";} restOfText{}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ran your code in a tableview cell and it worked exactly as expected for me. Is it possible that the attributes are getting reset elsewhere?

Comment: Did you check your UILabel constraints.

Comment: Can you show the result of `debugPrint(cell.label.text!)` ?

Comment: @jancakes Yep, you were right. I am a moron and overwrote the entirety of cell.label.text later in the function. Thank you for prompting me to reassess.

Comment: no problem! glad you found the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as written works no problem. I accidentally overwrote cell.label.text later. Whoops

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `NSRange` value with length 1. For Swift strings use the dedicated `NSRange` initializer taking the `String.Index` range and the target string

```
let string = cell.label.text!
let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(...string.startIndex, in: string ))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result of your code is exactly the same as the result of mine.

Comment: I did a quick test in a Playground and got the expected result (first character in red)

Comment: I must have something else screwed up then... Can't figure out why the part of the string within the range specified just disappears for me.

Comment: @CollinBell This code is more correct than your code. Your code will fail with most Emoji characters.

Comment: But once in `NSAttributedString`, isn't it taking the range as "NSString/NSAttributedString" does? Not no issue with length conversion between utf8 and utf16?

Comment: @Larme Please try `let string = "Hello"` and `NSRange(location:0, length:4)`...